# How to change php/mysql site to static site

Tags: php, html, performance, caching, joomla

I've got large joomla app on my server and I want to migrate its live view to another server. But due to server performance reasons, server admin want's only static html/css sites with js eventually so i can't copy whole site. Of course getting sources manually is not an option because there is a lot of sites and it will take to much time to generate it again on every article update.

1. Is there a way to do it?
2. I am thinking about using cache to achieve this, what You think about it? If the cache generated on my server and then copied to target server will do the job (I think not because of different URL's)?
3. Any ideas to handle this?

I know this is strange, but I must do it somehow =/

Comment: No, there is no method to migrate a Joomla site to a basic static html/css site.

Comment: Check the sfyns answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to prepare the site, remove dynamic elements like contact forms, search boxes, etc..., and then:

```
nice wget --mirror -e robots=off --page-requisites --html-extension -nv --base=./ --convert-links --directory-prefix=./ http://www.example.com/
```

This will create a static archive of the site example.com, on a *nix system, located in the current directory.

A google search for "joomla static archive" turned up this post: http://vaasa.hacklab.fi/2013/11/28/howto-make-a-static-copy-of-joomla-site-with-wget/

The Drupal related documentation may also be helpful to understanding some aspects of the process: https://drupal.org/node/27882

Comment: It works fine You're the Boss